# Matlab imnoise Poisson doing nothing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise

Basically I have:

```
sourceImage = im2double(imread(srcPath));

noiseImage = imnoise(sourceImage,'poisson');
```

The problem is that both sourceImage and noiseImage look pretty the same.

Indeed if I do

```
norm(sourceImage - noiseImage)
```

I get `1.4810e-05` (this seems a too low difference)

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If `srcPath` describes a standard 8bpp image, then the "problem" is easily solved by not using `im2double`. Now, according to `imnoise` documentation, when the input is described by doubles, matlab expects them to be scaled by 1e12. One way to adjust for this is to normalize your image to [0, 1] and upscale by something like 10e12, 50e12, etc, then add noise and downscale back.

Comment: @mmgp: Hmm that's tricky. Post an answer anyway if you want i will +1 it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two ways to handle your problem, based on the own description of `imnoise` for Poisson distribution (I will call it as `p`):

1) Keep the image described by `srcPath` in the integer domain

2) Manually upscale and downscale your image, see http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242444

The reasoning for case 1) is that `p` doesn't scale integer values. But, when using doubles, `p` assumes they are scaled by 1e12, but they are not in your case. As a analogy, it would be like truncating doubles in the range [0, 1] and expect to get integers different than 0 or 1.

Comment: I may not have given enough emphasis on the importance of the included link, but it describes the exactly same problem and there is a solution for dealing with doubles. Not sure if you followed it.

Comment: my srcPath image is already in floating point (maybe that's the problem)

Comment: Oh, ok, I wasn't aware of that. Point 2) still applies then.

Comment: Regarding image in floating point. Is necessary to do im2double() if my image is in floating point? And also if you can write a snippet of code with upscale and downscaling i would greatly appreciate it. Code on mathworks.com is pretty unreadable

Comment: Well, it may or not be necessary. If your image is in floating point, but not in the range [0, 1], then im2double scales it to fit that range. So it depends on how is your data formatted.