# Adding poisson noise does nothing to an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I'm trying to add poisson noise to a very simple image in MATLAB.

```
im = ones(256, 256);
noisy = imnoise(im, 'poisson');
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765312/matlab-imnoise-poisson-doing-nothing/13772455) answer, I tried this as well.

```
im = ones(256, 256);
noisy = imnoise(im2double(im), 'poisson');
```

to no avail.

I've also tried it with `im = zeros(256, 256)` but that did nothing as well.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation of `imnoise`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html#mw_226e1fb2-f53a-4e49-9bb1-6b167fc2eac1):

> If `I` is double precision, then input pixel values are interpreted as means of Poisson distributions scaled up by `1e12`. For example, if an input pixel has the value `5.5e-12`, then the corresponding output pixel will be generated from a Poisson distribution with mean of `5.5` and then scaled back down by `1e12`.

This scaling does not happen when the input is `uint8`:

```
im = ones(256, 256, 'uint8');
noisy = imnoise(im, 'poisson');
```

In the case of double-precision, there are two issues:

1. The scaling of `1e12` seems excessive. This means that the output is taken from a Poisson distribution with a mean of `1e12`, then divided by `1e12`. The mean will be `1`, and the standard deviation will be `sqrt(1e-12)=1e-6`. That is, the standard deviation will be tiny and the change in intensity will not be visible. If you use `format long`, MATLAB will show you these values:

   ```
   >> format long
   >> min(noisy(:))
   ans =
        0.999996115518000
   >> max(noisy(:))
   ans =
        1
   ```
2. This last result (max is 1) indicates that MATLAB clips the results to the [0,1] range, because double-precision images are expected to be in that range. Thus, the distribution returned by your code is not Poisson, it is Poisson clipped at its mean.

So, for floating-point images, scale them appropriately first:

```
noisy = imnoise(im * 1e-12, 'poisson') * 1e12;
```

(or use a different factor if that suits you better).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with an image I took off the internet from [here.](https://imgflip.com/i/1s4lgu)

```
I = imread('stick.jpg');
imshow(I)
J = imnoise(I,'poisson');
imshow(J)
```

[image]
[image]

If I take your's and change it to Gaussian you will see a difference.

```
I = ones(256,256);
imshow(I)
J = imnoise(I,'gaussian');
imshow(J)
```

I haven't read enough on this but my belief would be because the image has homogeneous intensity [throughout.](https://ruiminpan.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/the-curious-case-of-poisson-noise-and-matlab-imnoise-command/)

[image]

Comment: It is because you chose poisson, change it to gaussian.

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation as to why this works and poison doesn’t?

Comment: @Carpetfizz regardless of matlab implementation here, poisson noise happens in low photon count scenarios, it makes sense you don't have any in a super bright image